# Creating random relationships between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database with 1,000 companies, 1,000 persons and 2,000 bank accounts. I would like to randomly pair each company with one bank account and each person with one bank with no bank account connected to more than one entity.

I have tried the following without success:

```
MATCH (a:PERSON), (b:BANK_ACCOUNT)
WHERE NOT (a)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->(:BANK_ACCOUNT) 
AND NOT (b)<-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]-(:COMPANY|:PERSON)
MERGE (a)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->(b);

MATCH (COMPANY), (b:BANK_ACCOUNT)
WHERE NOT (a)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->(:BANK_ACCOUNT) 
AND NOT (b)<-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]-(:COMPANY|:PERSON)
MERGE (a)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->(b);
```

Can you help?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing something like this with APOC `rock_n_roll`

```
// iterate over people 
// and create a relationship to one bank
// that does not already have the HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT
CALL apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll(
    'MATCH (a:PERSON)
     WHERE NOT (a)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->() 
     RETURN a AS a',
    'WITH {a} AS a MATCH (b:BANK_ACCOUNT)
     WHERE NOT (b)<-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->() 
     WITH a, b
     LIMIT 1 
     MERGE (a)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->(b)',
    100
)

// repeat, but for companies this time
CALL apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll(
    'MATCH (a:COMPANY)
     WHERE NOT (a)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->() 
     RETURN a AS a',
    'WITH {a} AS a 
     MATCH (b:BANK_ACCOUNT)
     WHERE NOT (b)<-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->() 
     WITH a, b
     LIMIT 1 
     MERGE (a)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->(b)',
    100
)
```

Alternatively, with a small change you could do it in one pass too

```
CALL apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll(
    'MATCH (a)
     WHERE a:PERSON or a:COMPANY
     AND NOT (a)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->() 
     RETURN a AS a',
    'WITH {a} AS a 
     MATCH (b:BANK_ACCOUNT)
     WHERE NOT (b)<-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->() 
     WITH a, b
     LIMIT 1 
     MERGE (a)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->(b)',
    100
)
```

If you wanted to make the relationships a little more random rather than the order they were added you could a line to randomize the driving MATCH statement.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll(
    'MATCH (a)
     WHERE a:PERSON or a:COMPANY
     AND NOT (a)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->() 
     RETURN a AS a, rand() AS random
     ORDER BY random',
    'WITH {a} AS a 
     MATCH (b:BANK_ACCOUNT)
     WHERE NOT (b)<-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->() 
     WITH a, b, rand() AS random
     ORDER BY random
     LIMIT 1 
     MERGE (a)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->(b)',
    100
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With so few nodes you should be able to do this easily using APOC collection functions for shuffling and zipping:

```
MATCH (b:BANK_ACCOUNT)
WITH collect(b) as accounts
WITH apoc.coll.shuffle(accounts) as accounts

MATCH (p:PERSON)
WITH accounts, collect(p) as persons
UNWIND apoc.coll.zip(persons, accounts[..1000]) as personAccount
WITH accounts, personAccount[0] as person, personAccount[1] as account
CREATE (person)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->(account)

WITH distinct accounts[1000..] as accounts

MATCH (c:COMPANY)
WITH accounts, collect(c) as companies
UNWIND apoc.coll.zip(companies, accounts) as companyAccount
WITH companyAccount[0] as company, companyAccount[1] as account
CREATE (company)-[:HAS_BANK_ACCOUNT]->(account)
```